# C++ swap content of two void*

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, void-pointers

Is it possible to swap the content of two void pointers ? I tried swapping the values by dereferencing the two pointers:

```
void* a = (void*)50;
void* b = (void*)90;
*a = *b;
```

However, the last line throws an error since it's impossible to dereference a void pointer.

I think it can be achieved by first casting the value of b to an int and then cast it back to a void* like this:

```
void* a = (void*)50;
void* b = (void*)90;

int value = (int)b;
a = (void*)value; //a now equals b
```

Unfortunately, that requires us to know what type a and b are "supposed" to be (I don't know if such a description is correct), in that case, they were ints. Is it possible to swap the content of two void pointers without knowing their "original" types ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::swap(a, b)`?

Comment: Void pointers should be avoided. Why are you using them?

Comment: Are you talking about swapping the pointers or swapping the objects they point to?

Comment: Swapping the data/objects/bytes they point to

Comment: watch out what you've done here: `void* a = (void*)50;` this declares `a` as a pointer to `void` and points it at memory address 50. It doesn't store 50 at the address pointed to by `a`, it makes `a` point to data at address 50, and 50 is almost certainly not a valid address for use. Usually the first couple thousand addresses are verboten and never used because it makes trapping accidental null pointer accesses easier. `*a = *b;` then assigns the data at a bad memory address to the data at another bad memory address, and BOOM

Comment: Try a test case:  `float f = 3.14f; char c = 'T'; void * pf = (void *)&f; void * pc = (void *)&pc;`  You can't swap the objects that `pf` and `pc` point to because their target type info has been changed, yet they are both `void *` pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's not possible. In order to do such a thing, the information about the sizes of the objects pointed to by the two pointers would have to be present at runtime somewhere, which isn't the case. Furthermore, there are types that are not trivially copyable, and as such, swapping their bytes might not swap their values, and could cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to swap the content of two void pointers without knowing their "original" types?

If you have no knowledge of the types then no, it is not possible. At the very least, you must know the size of the type. And that is sufficient only for [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) types.